# Springboot RabbitMQ low performance problem

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, consumer

I use rabbitmq as consumer.The procedur send to almost 200 messages per second.Size of message ~4.65KB and also the envorinment of consumers enough capacity. No matter what I do, the performance cannot exceed 40~60 messages per second altough queue has a lot of messages. My rabbit configuration like this

```
 @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter messageListener) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        container.setQueueNames(this.queue);
        container.setConcurrentConsumers(80);
        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(400);
        container.setConsecutiveActiveTrigger(1);
        container.setConsecutiveIdleTrigger(1);
        container.setPrefetchCount(400);
        container.setConsumerStartTimeout(100);
        container.setReceiveTimeout(100);
        container.setTxSize(200);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        container.setAutoStartup(true);
        return container;
    }
@Bean
    public MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter(NotificationListener listener) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(listener, "handleMessage");
    }
 public void handleMessage(final byte[] message) throws Throwable {
        Date dt1 = new Date();
        System.out.println("Received" + dt1);
}
```

I tried @RabbitListener annotation and also channel.basicConsume() method but not working

Comment: Your `prefetchCount` is too high. It means one consumer will get 400 messages at once. So every other consumer will just be doing nothing at all. You should lower that number to allow more threads to consume messages.

Comment: Thanks for advice but No matter what i try, the average messages per second doesn't change.(~45 consumed messages) though queeu has grather than 1000 messages. My envoirment has 4 core and 12GB ram

Comment: Your full code of the Listener is just the System.out.println ?

Comment: Yes,Although listeners does just system.out.println,consumers can not consume messages more than ~45 per second

Comment: Can you share how you configure the ConnectionFactory ?

Comment: as you can see listeners stop working randomly  but i can't see any cause of this
14:30:20,707 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-2583) Mesaj
14:30:20,707 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-2585) Mesaj
14:30:20,745 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-2591) Mesaj--Almot 38 milisecond stop working
14:30:20,746 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-2596) Mesaj
14:30:20,746 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-2597) Mesaj
14:30:20,747 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-2593) Mesaj
14:30:20,747 INFO  [stdout] (Thread-2592) Mesaj

Comment: I get connection info from application prop. When i watch the logs i see that consumers not working ~10-20 miliseconds randomly times but queeu has a lot of messages.  That's my conection infos:
spring.rabbitmq.host=170.22.5.40 spring.rabbitmq.port=5676
spring.rabbitmq.username=FASTUSER spring.rabbitmq.password=FASTPSW spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true spring.rabbitmq.ssl.verify-hostname=false spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host =/hft rabbitmq.exchange=EX01 rabbitmq.routingkey=FAST rabbitmq.queue=FASTQE0 spring.rabbitmq.ssl.algorithm=tlsv1.2

Comment: Have you tried to lower the number of consumers and maxConsumers ? In your case I don't see why you would try more than 4. Sometimes too many threads can cause huge performance issues. I would try to use visualVM to check where the JVM is wasting its time to further investigate